# How to configure trustStore for camel-https4

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-camel, spring-camel

I've declared my route like this(took idea from http://camel.apache.org/http4.html):

```
@Component
public class MyRouteDefinition extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setType("pkcs12");
        ksp.setResource(PushRoutesDefinition.class.getResource("/keystore.p12").getPath());
        ksp.setPassword("password");

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
        kmp.setKeyPassword("password");

        SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

        HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
        httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

        //TO HTTPS
        from(...)
        .to("https4://localhost:8080/load")
        .process(exchange -> {
                    Integer responseCode = 
             exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
             log.debug("The response code is: {}", responseCode);
         }
    }
```

but I see error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:58)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
10.01.18 16:58:00.070 [DefaultQuartzScheduler-MIS_UploadService_Worker-2] ERROR o.a.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob - Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-pc-1515592473370-0-3]. Caused by: [org.quartz.JobExecutionException - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
10.01.18 16:58:00.070 [DefaultQuartzScheduler-MIS_UploadService_Worker-2] INFO  org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job findAll./myGroup/myTimerName threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:61)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:58)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my issue.

```
@Component
public class MyRouteDefinition extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setType("pkcs12");
        ksp.setResource(PushRoutesDefinition.class.getResource("/keystore.p12").getPath());
        ksp.setPassword("password");

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
        kmp.setKeyPassword("password");

        TrustManagersParameters trustManagersParameters = new TrustManagersParameters();
        trustManagersParameters.setKeyStore(ksp);

        SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);
        scp.setTrustManagers(trustManagersParameters);

        HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
        httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

        //TO HTTPS
        from(...)
        .to("https4://localhost:8080/load")
        .process(exchange -> {
                    Integer responseCode = 
             exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
             log.debug("The response code is: {}", responseCode);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I've used the same code, but still facing the issue, what is the use PushRoutesDefinition class? in my case, I'm using type=jks and resource=truststore.jks file, here how to define the file path?, in my case file is there in src/resources(spring boot application) folder

Comment: KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
ksp.setType("jks");
ksp.setResource("kafka.client.truststore.jks");
ksp.setPassword("123456");
KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
kmp.setKeyPassword("123456");
TrustManagersParameters trustManagersParameters = new TrustManagersParameters();
trustManagersParameters.setKeyStore(ksp);
SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);
scp.setTrustManagers(trustManagersParameters);

Comment: HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

Comment: like these I'm using the configuration, can you please help me what might be the problem, is it the correct way to load the .jks file?